# Callback function for MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Am trying to figure out Kivy in Python and cannot find what I am doing wrong here. I have tried to resolve this bug multiple times but cannot do so. Please help.

P.S. This is not the main **MDApp** (it is Records(MDApp))class but  a Screen class from ScreenManager. don't know if that's the problem.

python code:

```
class Hall_of_Fame(Screen):
    def call(self, instance):
        if instance.icon=='pen-plus':
            current_win= 'Add_Record'
        elif instance.icon== 'archive-edit':
            current_win= 'Edit_Record'

        self.manager.current = current_win
```

kivy file snippet:

```
<Hall_of_Fame>:
    name:'Hall_of_Fame'
    MDlabel:
        text: 'landed'
        size: 34 

<Match>:
    id: Match
    name: 'Match'

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDScreen:        
            MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
                data: root.data_dic
                root_button_anim: True

                callback: app.call
```

what am I doing wrong?

(this is my first time asking a question here so sorry for any missing info I should have added)

terminal output:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\Downloads\RECO\Main.py", line 90, in <module>
     Records().run()
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 955, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 925, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "c:\Users\Downloads\RECO\Main.py", line 84, in build
     kiv =  Builder.load_file('layout.kv')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 407, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 660, in _apply_rule
     child.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 540, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 620, in _apply_rule
     cls = Factory_get(cname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 147, in __getattr__
     raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <MDlabel>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `kv`, `MDLabel` is spelled wrong. Note the uppercase `l`.